# Warning in publishing MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m getting this warning while publishing this code

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>
> "path", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures.
>
> Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your
>   project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor
>   architectures between your project and references,
>
> or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that
>   matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

How to solve this process , i have tried to make in build manager .. 
but i m getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Build-->Configuration Manager menu and change all of the platforms to be the same - probably x86.  Make sure to do **both** debug and release configurations.

Following on from your reply : you'll have to make sure that each referenced dll is also compiled for the same platform - ie all x86 or all x64.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I tried this ... but no luck